# Using Django for a website without separating static files

Tags: python, django

I want to move my website to django which has a lot of images and css files linked to it. Also it uses Application cache for caching the static files.Since I have other apps working on the django I want to move this static one also to the django.So is it possible to run a webpage without rendering the static files dynamically and use the page as static webpage only(static files path relative to html not using django's static folder)? How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the HTML is also static, you should just move everything (HTML and relative files) to a static folder (no need to separate the HTML template since it is static as well), and then you can map it to any URL you want using your web server, e.g. you can put them inside `{{ STATIC_ROOT }}/my-page/`, and map `example.com/my-page/` to that folder on the filesystem

Run `collectstatic`, Django will copy/generate the static files into your `STATIC_ROOT` folder on the filesystem https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic

Then use a web server like Apache or Nginx to serve your `/my-page` URL directly without hitting your Django app. (set in Django with `STATIC_URL`), while the other requests are forwarded to your Django app

So e.g. your Django app will run on 127.0.0.1:8000, while nginx runs on the default HTTP/HTTPS port, and uses e.g. `proxy_pass` to talk to your Django app for the dynamic content

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule

Comment: Thanks for the answer.It is one option...Can `ssi` be used for the same so that everything can run on same port of django app? I tried `ssi` but getting errors. I asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26075852/ssi-tag-not-working-didnt-have-permission-to-include-file)

Comment: On Apache server the urls are generated relative to `public_html dir`.So if using collectstatic I copy the static files in `STATIC_ROOT` then serving the files using apache server will produce urls like `example.com/static_root/my-page/`.I don't know how to map that to `example.com/my-page/` as u said.Can u please add some detail how to do that..