# SSI tag not working. [Didn't have permission to include file]

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to include a `static html` in my `html` page by giving absolute path. I am trying to use ssi for that.The code is:

settings.py:

```
...
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
from os.path import join
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ['c:\bunker\st\static\appcache',]
ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS =[(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/appcache')),] #For access permissions
...
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def home(request):
    return render(request, "a.html")
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^apps/','sp.views.home'),  #sp is app name
```

a.html:

```
{% ssi 'C:\bunker\st\static\appcache\index.html' parsed %}
```

But I obtain the following from the output

> [Didn't have permission to include file]

I have added `ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS` but still I am getting the error.

How to debug this?

Comment: The path of an SSI include must be absolute. So something like `/home/YOURNAME/YOURAPP/static/appcache/index.html`.

Comment: i am using windows 8.Edited and used absolute path (question edited) still same error..

Answer (score 0):

I resolved mine by using double quotes around the link. For example:

```
{% include "index.html" %}
```

Answer (score -1):

I resolved mine by changing all `'\'` to `'/'`.
EDIT: You may want to check to make sure nothing else is broken as well.